# Running custom linux images on Azure functions consumption plan

Tags: azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-container-service, azure-container-instances, azure-container-registry

Looks like Linux hosting for custom Functions containers are only supported on Dedicated (App Service) plans and Premium plans but not consumption plans. When I tried to do that I got errors about Linux workers not being available in the resource group.
While I can get my custom image to run on the premium plan, it is turning out to be far too expensive. Is there a work-around to running it in the consumption plan? Is there a consumption plan exclusively with Linux workers?
Also, what are cheaper alternatives for running a service (so far I have looked into Web Apps and Azure Container Instances) and I am looking for something cheaper.

My service will be rarely called and will include un-trusted code (coming from client in the form of JS), so I am looking for something that is cheap, responsive and can be integrated with container registries (I am running a Node svc).

Comment: May I know the price you can accept, if your service will be rarely called, you can choose B1, B2 or B3 plan(or even free plan) when you create the function.

Comment: Thank you Hury. I was hoping for around $50/mo per app.

Comment: Since every function app would need to be associated with a function plan and a storage account, can those be shared across different function apps to cut costs?
Meaning, I have a resource group = "testRG" in which I have plan = "testPlan" and a storage account = "testStorageAccount" and multiple azure function app's, all pointed to the same testPlan and testStorageAccount?

Comment: Yes, of course. You can deploy multiple function apps in one service plan and one storage account as long as you think the plan is enough.